# `length' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my code I keep getting error "undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass"
even after I remove the line it gives me this error "undefined method`each' for nil: NilClass" I am trying to display the practices listed by the doctor and the reviews for his services on my portal

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="center">
      <%= image_tag avatar_url(@user), class: "avatar-full" %>
      <% if current_user != @user %>
        <div class="row-space-2">
          <%= link_to "Send Message", conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id), method: 'post', class: "btn btn-primary wide" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Verification</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Email Address<br>
        Phone Number
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
    <h2><%= @user.fullname %></h2>

    <div class="description row-space-3">
      <%= @user.description %>
    </div>

    <h4>Listings (<%= @practices.length %>)</h4><br>

    <div class="row">
      <% @practices.each do |practice| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading preview">
              <%= image_tag room.photos[0].image.url(:medium) %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <%= link_to practice.speciality, practice %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <h4>Reviews</h4><br>

    <% @practices.each do |practice| %>
      <% if !practice.reviews.blank? %>
        <% practice.reviews.each do |review| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
              <%= image_tag avatar_url(review.user), class: "img-circle avatar-medium" %><br>
              <%= review.user.fullname %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <%= link_to room.listing_name, room %><br>
              <%= review.comment %><br>
              <%= review.created_at.strftime("%v") %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help! I have been stuck for days with this error

This is my controller Code:

```
class PracticesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_practice, only: [:show,:edit,:update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!,except: [:show]

  def index
    @practices = current_user.practices
  end

  def show
    @photos = @practice.photos
    @booked = Appointment.where("practice_id = ? AND user_id = ?",      @practice.id, current_user.id).present? if current_user@reviews = @practice.reviews
    @hasReview = @reviews.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) if current_user
  end

  def new
    @practice = current_user.practices.build
  end

  def create
    @practice = current_user.practices.build(practice_params)
    if @practice.save
        if params[:images]
            params[:images].each do |image|
                @practice.photos.create(image: image)
            end
        end
        @photos = @practice.photos
        redirect_to edit_practice_path(@practice), notice: "Saved..."
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    if current_user.id == @practice.user.id
        @photos = @practice.photos
    else
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "You don't have permission."
    end
  end

  def update
    if @practice.update(practice_params)
        if params[:images]
            params[:images].each do |image|
                @practice.photos.create(image: image)
            end
        end
        redirect_to edit_practice_path(@practice), notice: "Updated..."
    else
        render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def set_practice
    @practice = Practice.find(params[:id])
  end

  def practice_params
    params.require(:practice).permit(:dr_first_name,:dr_last_name,:experience,:speciality,:address,:professional_statement,:is_insurance,:insurance,:zip_code)
  end
end
```

As requested I have also posted the Controller's code

Comment: `@practices` seem to be `nil`. Make sure that you load the practices correctly in your controller.

Comment: can you please put your controllers code

Comment: posted controllers code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try`.

```
<h4>Listings (<%= @practices.try(:length, 0) %>)</h4>
```

It will either return the length when available, or 0 in case it's nil.

You can also use try on each like this:

```
<% @practices.try(:each) do |practice| %>
```

But in this case you might want to surround it with an `if @practices.any?` instead, in case you'd want to display something particular when there are no practices.

Comment: You're welcome. But bear in mind that if your variable should not be nil, it will not raise an exception anymore... So you might want to make sure that's the expected behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Your `@practices` variable must be empty, so replace

```
<h4>Listings (<%= @practices.length %>)</h4><br>
```

with

```
<h4>Listings (<%= (@practices.to_s.empty?)? 'no length' : @practices.length %>)</h4>
```

That will check if `@practices` variable is empty or not, and the prevent the `.length` operation on a `NilClass`.

Comment: That fixed the listings problem
Now....Its giving error for this line
     <% @practices.each do |practice| %>

Comment: So the problem is that `@practices` is empty, you have to check here too, because now its calling `.each` method on a nil. Make sense to you?